# Want to choose a random number and not have it picked again until all numbers have gone through

Tags: go

I'm looking to pick a random number from 1-6 but if for example 1 is picked by the program I want to make sure it is not again used until 2-6 has been picked. I want to do this in order to have a chance to go through all options instead of having the same option 2 or maybe 3 times in a row since there are only 6 options. Any ideas please?

```
//choose random number for recipe
rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
myrand := random(1, 6)
fmt.Println(myrand)
```

...

function that processes it

```
//random number function
func random(min, max int) int {
    return rand.Intn(max-min) + min
```

}

The part of my program that uses myrand from each run is used in a if statement and is tied to the recipe that will be picked for the day

```
//choose random number for recipe
rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
myrand := random(1, 6)
fmt.Println(myrand)

//test below of random replacement
list := rand.Perm(6)
for i, _ := range list {
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", list[i]+1)
}

//logic for recipe to choose
if myrand == 1 {
    fmt.Println(1)
    printRecipeOfTheDay(recipe1)
} else if myrand == 2 {
    fmt.Println(2)
    printRecipeOfTheDay(recipe2)
} else if myrand == 3 {
    fmt.Println(3)
    printRecipeOfTheDay(recipe3)
} else if myrand == 4 {
    fmt.Println(4)
}
```

}

I'm wondering if I'm doing something incorrectly ? I'm not sure how I can use the list on every run to generate a new number (myrand) and the program will be able to remember what the last number (myrand) was when it ran the previous time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rand.Perm(6)` and then loop through the result.

For example, here is code to print the numbers 1-6 in a random order, with no repeats:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "math/rand"

func main(){
    list := rand.Perm(6);
    for i, _ := range list {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", list[i]+1);
    }
}
```

Note that we've added 1 to everything, since `Perm(6)` returns 0-5 and you want 1-6. After you've used all six, call `rand.Perm(6)` again for six new numbers.

Comment: Interesting, is there an example I can follow?

Comment: Would you know how I can choose one particular value from the list and read it into a variable to be processed? For example can I put the value 1 into a variable called "value1" and then run a if else statement on "value1"?